# ReferenceError in js console -SCRIPT5009: 'channel_click' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting a "SCRIPT5009: 'channel_click' is undefined" error in IE9 within the js console. The code works in chrome & firefox but it suddenly stopped while clicking the link to initiate the js sequences in IE9.

I have been trying to figure this out with no success but what I have done was timed a series of events to occur which:

```
1) onclick - toggle div to hide
2) wait 1500 
3) open print command
- User closes the window to return to page
4) wait 3500 toggle div to show again
```

The reason why I do this is I don't want the print preview to pick up these series of divs when the user decides to print the page.

Javacript:

```
<script>
//WAITS UNTIL EXCESS IS HIDDEN THEN FIRES PRINT COMMAND 
function channel_click(){

// anon wrapper function, 2 second delay
setTimeout( function () {
window.print();return false;
} , 1500 );

}
</script>


<script>
//HIDES EXCESS IN PREP FOR FIRING PRINT COMMAND PREVIOUS FUNCTION EXECUTES IN BETWEEN FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS
$(".hideshow").click(function () {
$("#header,#footer").toggle("slow");

setTimeout( function () {
$("#header,#footer").toggle("slow");
} , 3500 );
$('.modal-backdrop').hide();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="hideshow" onclick="channel_click()">Print Preview</a>

<div id="header">
    <div class="pull-left">
    <h1>Edt Mode</h1>
    <h6 style="padding-bottom: 30px;">Some informational text here</h6>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    <h1>PRINT ME!</h1>
    <h6 style="padding-bottom: 30px;">PRINT ME -  PRINT ME - PRINT ME</h6>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="pull-left">
    <h1>Edt Mode</h1>
    <h6 style="padding-bottom: 30px;">Some informational text here</h6>
</div>

<div class="model-backdrop">wow this is some more text</div>
```

Comment: actually your code looks fine, you're only missing `<script type="text/javascript">`. does that help? you may also need to wrap your script into `$(document).ready(/**/);`

Comment: modern browsers (as hes using chrome) it doesn't need `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @Sandeep you would be well-advised to use it, there are some engines rendering also other script types, so browsers don't fail because of trying.

Comment: ya i agree with you and i always use it. but that wont be the problem in this case. and i have posted and answer with fiddle down here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you load you javascript file before you try to use it in the html?
If you do that that's not the problem but if you don't try to link to the .js file at the end of your html file.

If you don't want this to be nessecary you have to wrap your channel_click within a window.onload or if you use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function channel_click() {
        ....
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing onclick from your anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="hideshow">Print Preview</a>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function channel_click(){    
    // anon wrapper function, 2 second delay
    setTimeout( function () {
         window.print();return false;
     } , 1500 );    
 }

    $(document).ready(function() {  //add this
        $(".hideshow").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#header,#footer").toggle("slow");
            channel_click(); //call print

           setTimeout( function () {
              $("#header,#footer").toggle("slow");
           } , 3500 );
           $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is working as u expected

http://jsbin.com/imimom/2

Answer (score 0):

Out of that your html is not well-formed, I don't see something wrong there. Maybe you can provide us with the complete markup?